# Galleria module - style top:

Tags: javascript, css, module, drupal-7, galleria

I'm trying to optimize my Galleria module for Drupal 7. Everything goes OK except one thing. `<img>` tag has directly added style - top: 50px. I think its added with JavaScript but I can't find it! I've tried to override this style with CSS inside Drupal Template and inside module CSS's but still nothing. I'll bite it with my teeth cause I'm trying to remove it from a few days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check, where the style is coming from using i.e Firebug for FF. Firebug gives you a complete list with inheritance and overriding rules. You may be able to see why your style wasn't applied.

If the style is added by JavaScript it's normally an inline style on the tag itself. You can override it in your css by using `top: 0 !important;`

Comment: In firebug its shown as style applied to .element (which means <img style= ... > ). But !importen worked it out and I've learned new thing ;) Thank You very much